# Why is the <__main_.ClassName at object 0xxxxxxxx> is showing? And how to get the actual results?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am making a simple class, here is the code:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, character):
        self.character= character       

Sara = Player("Sara")
```

Nothing fancy, when ever i run this it gives the following result:

```
>>> print Sara
<__main__.Player object at 0xxxxxxxxx>
```

How can i stop the last line <**main**.Pl.....> from executing?

Comment: what do you expect to happen? Python is telling you that it has created a `Player` object

Comment: you need to return your result if you want to print something.

Comment: I want it to return the string 'Sara'

Comment: then you need to `print Sara.character`

Comment: or define a `__str __` method that returns `'self.character'` (see duplicate question link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `__repr__` and `__str__` functions in your class so the `print` function knows what to print correctly. Please change your class to the example below and try again.

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, character):
        self.character = character  

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.character

    def __str__(self):
        return self.character
```

Comment: It's working! The same way Sara.character would execute. Do you have any good articles on these two functions?

Comment: Sure, @Belle, you can take a look at Python's documentation for input and output: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html. If my answer helped you please accept it as correct :-)